# Initialization outside of conditionals

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, integer

I was a newbie, so sorry for my silly question.

Here's the error:
Test.java:19: error: variable y might not have been initialized

Just wondering how I can retain the value of 'y' without changing everything else outside the conditional block. I know (but not really) why this is erroring, because 'y' isn't defined outside the else block.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x, y;
            System.out.print("enter value: ");
            x = kb.nextInt();
            if (x != 5) {
                System.out.println("invalid value");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
                y = 10;
            }
            System.out.println("y = " + y);
        }
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as if and else loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.print("enter value: ");
int x = kb.nextInt();
int y =0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either initialize it, or put the `System.out.println` inside the else statement where you initialize y.

```
else
{
    y = 10;
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As local variables are not initialized automatically you will have to initialize them before using

Answer (score 0):

`int x, y = 0;`

Do what the error message says and initialise y

Comment: This will only initialize `y`.

Comment: x is initialised before the if block